# Permanently lose hearts when you take damage

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I want that if the player takes damage and the player permanently loses that hearts.

```
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;


@EventHandler
    public void EntityDamage(EntityDamageEvent event) {
        Entity e = event.getEntity();
        if (e instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) e;
            double newhealth = player.getHealth();
            player.setMaxHealth(newhealth);
        }
    }
```

i use this code but this only reduces hearts after the second damage event

Answer (score 5):

`player.getHealth()` gets you the health of the player *before* its modification.
By looking into [the event's documentation](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/entity/EntityDamageEvent.html) i found this solution :

You can calculate the new health with `event.getFinalDamage()` :

```
double newhealth = player.getHealth() - event.getFinalDamage();
player.setMaxHealth(newhealth);
```

Hope it will help you !

PS: If you just want the player not to regenerate you can change the 'NaturalRegeneration' gamerule (but it will still allow the regeneration effect)

Comment: nope it does not work

Comment: @VoidCube_ and what does it do that is not what you expect ?